# É possível interceptar chamadas a funções de uma classe?

Tags: php

Em uma aplicação de vários níveis de usuário, nem todos podem acessar/usar aos mesmos métodos, existe alguma forma de interceptar a chamada de um método/função para que se possa fazer uma validação de acordo com o nível do usuário?

EX:
 Usuário comum tenta criar outro usuário, acessando **"usuarios/criar"**, a chamada seria algo assim:

```
Class usuarios {

  function criar () {
   // cria usuario
  }

}
```

O ideal seria:

```
Class usuarios {

   function __intercept($function_name) {

     $normal_methods = array('perfil', 'deslogar');
     $admin_methods = array('criar','excluir','editar', 'perfil', 'deslogar');


    if(tiver permisao) {
  in_array(...);
    //continue
    } else { 
    // redireciona
     }


   }

   function criar (){
   //cria usuario
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu recomendo você a criar uma **tabela** no seu banco de dado por exemplo: **tbl_permissoes**

Tabela **tbl_usuarios**

```
+----------------------------+
| ID   | USERNAME | PASSWORD |
+----------------------------+
|    1 |   USER01 | PASSWORD |
|    2 |   USER02 | PASSWORD |
|    3 |   USER03 | PASSWORD |
+----------------------------+
```

Tabela **tbl_permissoes**: contém uma coluna **user_id**, e as demais colunas como no exemplo abaixo são as áreas ou métodos que o usuário pode ou não ter acesso, sendo que **0** não tem permissão e **1** tem permissão.

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| ID   | USER_ID | CREATE | EDIT | DELETE |
+-----------------------------------------+
|    1 |       1 |      1 |    0 |      0 |
|    1 |       2 |      1 |    1 |      1 |
|    1 |       3 |      0 |    0 |      1 |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Como estou sem acesso a um banco de dados no momento, fiz um teste em https://ideone.com/WFDIB8

```
<?php
$Users = [
    1 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'nome' => 'USER01',
        'permissoes' => [
            'create' =>  1,
            'edit' => 0,
            'delete' => 0
        ]
    ],
    2 => [
        'id' => 2,
        'nome' => 'USER02',
        'permissoes' => [
            'create' =>  1,
            'edit' => 1,
            'delete' => 0
        ]
    ],
    3 => [
        'id' => 3,
        'nome' => 'USER03',
        'permissoes' => [
            'create' =>  1,
            'edit' => 1,
            'delete' => 1
        ]
    ],
    4 => [
        'id' => 4,
        'nome' => 'USER04',
        'permissoes' => [
            'create' =>  0,
            'edit' => 0,
            'delete' => 1
        ]
    ]
];


Class usuarios {
    /**
     * Função para verificar se o usuário logado
     * tem permissão para acessar uma página / método etc..
     */
    function verificarPermissao($UserID, $FuncName) {
        global $Users;
        if($Users[$UserID]["permissoes"][$FuncName] === 1) {
            $this->$FuncName();
        } else { 
            echo "Usuário não tem permissão para executar: {$FuncName}\n";
        }

    }

    function create() {
        echo "Usuário tem permissão para criar\n";
    }

    function edit() {
        echo "Usuário tem permissão para editar\n";
    }

    function delete() {
        echo "Usuário tem permissão para deletar\n";
    }
}

$user1 = new usuarios();
$user1->verificarPermissao(1, 'edit');
$user1->verificarPermissao(1, 'create');
$user1->verificarPermissao(1, 'delete');
echo "\n\n";
$user2 = new usuarios();
$user2->verificarPermissao(2, 'edit');
$user2->verificarPermissao(2, 'create');
$user2->verificarPermissao(2, 'delete');
echo "\n\n";
$user3 = new usuarios();
$user3->verificarPermissao(3, 'edit');
$user3->verificarPermissao(3, 'create');
$user3->verificarPermissao(3, 'delete');
echo "\n\n";
$user4 = new usuarios();
$user4->verificarPermissao(4, 'edit');
$user4->verificarPermissao(4, 'create');
$user4->verificarPermissao(4, 'delete');
```

Answer (score 0):

No PHP existe o método [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) que é chamado quando o método não existe na classe.

De repente você pode fazer algo assim:

```
public function __call($metodo, $parametros){
    if($metodo == "inserir"){
        // delega para o o codigo que insere
    }
    if($metodo == "excluir"){
        // delega para o o codigo que exclui
    }
    ...
}
```

Na hora de chamar você chama como se o método existisse, mas na prática é no `__call()`que ele vai entrar:

```
$usuarios->inserir();
```